# How to cache query for re-use in following UNION of queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, query-cache

I need to perform query, save the result and re-use it multiple times in one session (something like `WITH` in Oracle DB).

This is the query I want to save:

```
SELECT `event`.id, event.name
FROM attendant
INNER JOIN event ON attendant.fk_event = event.id
WHERE attendant.fk_user = 1

UNION

SELECT `event`.id, event.name
FROM organizer
INNER JOIN event ON organizer.fk_event = event.id
WHERE organizer.fk_user = 1

UNION

SELECT `event`.id, event.name
FROM invitation
INNER JOIN event ON invitation.fk_event = event.id
WHERE invitation.fk_user_to = 1
```

And then perform multiple queries like

```
SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....

UNION

SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....;
```

I've found `TEMPORARY TABLEs` but I don't think that I could use it since I need to perform this query for multiple different users at the time they run the request for events.

`VIEW` is also named, so I suppose there is the same problem.

What's the best solution to do this please?

Comment: Ok, I delete my answer, so I put as comment the query about get faster: `SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM event e
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'ATTENDANT'
    FROM attendant a
    WHERE a.fk_event = e.id
    AND a.fk_user = 1
) OR
EXISTS(
    SELECT 'ORGANIZER'
    FROM organizer o
    WHERE o.fk_event = e.id
    AND o.fk_user = 1
)
OR
EXISTS(
    SELECT 'INVITATION'
    FROM invitation i
    WHERE i.fk_event = e.id
    AND i.fk_user = 1
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, temporary tables are only visible within the session, and materialized views are not available in MySQL. There are several options (including the ones you have mentioned). I will name your original query as `SELECT ...`:

- The `WITH` Oracle keyword is equivalent to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`:

  ```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE savedquery AS SELECT ...; -- you execute this for every connection
  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....;
  ```

  You will have to create it for every connection.
- A `VIEW` is shared among connections, but it is not an actual table- it can be executed in two ways, by creating a temporary table at the beginning of the execution or by executing the corresponding subquery:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW savedquery 
  ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE  -- you probably want to use temptable algorithm
  AS SELECT ...;         -- you execute this only once

  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....;
  ```

  If you were using 5.6, the subquery algorithm may be better, but this is without knowing the actual query.
- As materialized views are not an option, you can emulate them by creating a real table, that will be shared among connections:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE savedquery AS SELECT ...;
  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM savedquery WHERE .....;
  ```

  The problem with this is that it is not automatically updated (you have to do that with triggers or any other way); the positive thing is that you can add indexes (unlike views).

The problem is that your original query and your derived query are probably not going to be very efficient, and you probably could modify it to perform better, but that is another question...

Comment: So I'm gonna go with temp tables and recreate them for every connection. About efficiency of my query - I've had no idea that it could be performed better. Could you please tell me more in chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17675/query-efficiency?tab=general

Comment: @2rec you can use `MyISAM` or `MEMORY` `ENGINE`s to avoid transactional overhead, is up to you. Sorry, not available right now.